# MongoDB/Mongoose Populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Working with Mongoose "[Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)" - So far I'm unable to successfully get the "Food" model to populate the "User" model.

**The goal is to be able to save a "Food" to a user.**

USER MODEL:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    foods: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}],
    easy: {type: Boolean, default: false}, 
});
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose)
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

FOOD MODEL:

```
var foodSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name:      { type: String, required: false, unique: true },
     author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: "User",
        },
   }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model("Food", foodSchema);
```

GET ROUTE

```
 router.get("/dashboard", function (req, res) {

        User.find({currentUser: req.user})
        .populate({path: 'foods'}).
        exec(function (err, foods) {
        if (err) return (err);

        console.log('The food is:', req.user.foods.name);

      });  
    });
```

POST ROUTE:

```
router.post("/dashboard", function(req, res, next) {

    User.update({ id: req.session.passport.user }, {
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user) {

            var newFood = new Food({
            name: req.body.currentBreakfast,
            image: 'test',
            });

            user.foods = newFood
            user.save();
            });
        });
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `ref` field in your user schema for foods to be populated while querying user.

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   username: String,
   password: String,
   foods: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Food' }],
   easy: {type: Boolean, default: false}, 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! User.foods now gives an object like ["5c543cc8ec51174b58d047d0"] - How do I get it to show the food name?

Comment: After adding ref in UserSchema, you can user populate() in find query

Answer (score 1):

You can user this query.

```
await User.find({currentUser: req.user}).populate('foods')
```

Comment: Thanks! :) user.foods.name is undefined. user.foods is an object. Any thoughts?

Comment: Update my answer. Kindly check

Comment: Gave it a try. user.foods.name is undefined. user.foods is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will auto-populate data

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  foods: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'Food'}}],
  easy: {type: Boolean, default: false}, 
});
UserSchema.pre('find', prepopulate)

function prepopulate(){
  return this.populate('foods')
}
```

Comment: What does auto-populate have to do with the question? :/