# Mongoose Populate only shows Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Using Mongoose's populate to add users favorite "foods" into the user object.

Set up:

```
User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user) {

            var newFood = new Food({
            name: "tacos",
            image: 'test',
            });

            user.foods = newFood
            user.save();
```

Then:

```
router.get("/dashboard", function (req, res) {

        User.find({currentUser: req.user})
        .populate({path: 'foods'}).
        exec(function (err, foods) {
        if (err) return (err);
```

When I console.log user.foods.name is undefined. user.foods is an object

**How do I get the user.foods.name?** In this case expecting "tacos"

Comment: Where do you console `user.foods.name`?

Comment: See full code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478537/mongodb-mongoose-populate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB/Mongoose Populate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478537/mongodb-mongoose-populate)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is, that you are not really understanding (yet) how `callbacks` and `async/await` works. Your code-execution is not going the way you are wanting it to go, so you are landing on parts where variables have not been set yet.

This problem cannot be answer with just this specific question/answer.

Please watch some tutorials (or read, if you prefere) about what callbacks are.

If you are free to choose the version of your JS, then i suggest you use `async/await`. It makes things MUCH more structured, readable and understanable.

BUT: You first fully need to understand it. Just copy-pasting it will result in errors and misconceptions (trust me).

Just google for those guides, i personally would search for youtube-tutorials (there are hundreds of nice structured ones).